# How to return a value from a non integer input between 0-5 from an output range of 0-320 in map() method

Tags: arduino-ide, c++

I am experimenting using the map() method in an ArduinoIDE sketch in an attempt to obtain a pixel position for a horizontal meter in the range 0-320 from an input value in the range 0-5.  However, when I do this I see in the method that the input must be 'long' type.  Here's my example code:

```
  float voltage = 2.5;
  float meterPosition = map(voltage, 0, 5, 0, 320);
  tft.fillRect(0, 0, meterPosition, 10, TFT_GREEN);
  tft.setCursor(10, 70);
  tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.println(voltage);
  tft.println(meterPosition);
```

But when I run this, despite the input value being 50% of the input range, I expected the meterPosition value to be 160, but it is 128, due I think because the values for this method must be of type 'long' and so the 'float' value is rounded and becomes a 'long' type (I think that's what is happening!!).

I am confused as to the function of the map() method if you are unable to map any range to any other range without using decimals as the input.  I am obviously missing something here, so what do I need to change in my map() method code for it to work in my example please, if I am unable to use floats?

Thanks.
John

Comment: What about just saying `float meterPosition = voltage * 64.0 ;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed, the `map()` function is meant to work with the
`long` data type. Here is [its implementation](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-API/blob/1.4.0/api/Common.cpp):

```cpp
long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max)
{
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

If you want to use floats, you could write a version of this function
that works with floats. Note, however, that since you are using zeros
for both `in_min` and `out_min`, the expression simplifies itself to the
point of becoming trivial:

```cpp
float meterPosition = voltage * 320 / 5.0;
```

I would suggest two small changes to this expression though:

- add parentheses around `(320 / 5.0)`: this ratio will then be
  evaluated at compile-time and you will save an expensive run-time
  floating-point division
- round to the nearest integer in order to minimize the error: your
  pixel position will have to be an integer anyway.

With these suggestions, we have:

```cpp
int meterPosition = round(voltage * (320 / 5.0));
```

Do not forget the `.0` in `5.0`, otherwise you would get an integer
division.

Note that using `map()` with ranges scaled by a factor 100 is not a
terribly good idea: you will waste quite a lot of CPU cycles doing
useless computations, and the result will be polluted by two rounding
errors instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for my stupidity folks!  I think I have realised how to do this, it is simply a matter of scaling the input values and input range by 100.